# Mostrar un calendario en español, y sin mostrar el mes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente código ya hecho, dada una entrada en formato dd/mm/aaaa:

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar

x = input()

A = datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y')
año = A.year
mes = A.month

print(calendar.month(año, mes)
```

Quisiera que lo que mostrara en pantalla fuera en español, y que no mostrara el nombre del mes. No sé si existe alguna forma de hacerlo.
De la siguiente forma:

```
lun mar mie jue vie sab dom
1     2   3   4   5   6   7
8     9  10  11  12  13  14
15   16  17  18  19  20  21
22   23  24  25  26  27  28
```

Comment: Nada te impide hacerlo, animo!

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Lo siento StarEn, pero aquí no podemos hacer todo tu código, por favor agrega a la pregunta lo que has intentado y el problema que tienes para que te podamos ayudar da forma adecuada.

Comment: Por si fuera de tu interés, la forma estándar de obtener nombres de fecha en un idioma particular es hacer uso del "locale". En tu caso consistiría en cambiar la última línea por `print(calendar.LocaleTextCalendar(locale="es_ES.utf8").formatmonth(año, mes))` Esto no elimina el nombre del mes (que sale ahora en castellano).

Comment: @abulafia ups, no vi tu comentario y publiqué una respuesta diciendo eso.

Comment: @DanteS. No pasa nada, tu respuesta extiende y elabora mi comentario. Un detalle por si quieres añadirlo a la respuesta, para saber qué valores de "locale" son los que se pueden usar, en linux puedes poner en una consola `locale -a` y te listará todos los posibles. Para español suele ser "es_ES.utf8", pero a menudo hay alias más cortos como "es".

Comment: @abulafia Gracias! Agregado!

Answer (score 3):

#### Introducción a la solución

Cito la [documentación de calendar.month](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month):

> Retorna el calendario de un mes en una cadena de varias líneas usando
> el formatmonth() de la clase TextCalendar.

Lo que significa que se puede lograr un equivalente a la función antes mencionada con:

```
calendar.TextCalendar().formatmonth(argumentos)
```

Por otro lado, existe una subclase de TextCalendar llamada [LocaleTextCalendar](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.LocaleTextCalendar), que nos permite configurar una configuración regional.

No dice cual sería la configuración regional para el español, pero probé con "es" y funciona.

#### Solución

Teniendo en cuenta ambas cosas, podemos crear la siguiente linea de código:

```
print(calendar.LocaleTextCalendar(locale='es').formatmonth(ano, mes))
```

Que implementada en tu código

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar

x = input()

fecha = datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y')
ano = fecha.year
mes = fecha.month

print(calendar.LocaleTextCalendar(locale='es').formatmonth(ano, mes))
```

E ingresada la fecha "12/12/2020" produce:

```
   diciembre 2020
lu ma mi ju vi sá do
    1  2  3  4  5  6
 7  8  9 10 11 12 13
14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27
28 29 30 31
```

Si quieres quitar el titulo, puedes separar el texto en dos según el primer salto de linea (\n) y tomar solo lo que viene después de este:

```
_, mes = calendar.LocaleTextCalendar(locale='es').formatmonth(ano, mes).split("\n", 1)

print(mes)
```

Que produce:

```
lu ma mi ju vi sá do
    1  2  3  4  5  6
 7  8  9 10 11 12 13
14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27
28 29 30 31
```

#### Edit

Cito comentario de @Abulafia:

> ... para saber qué valores de "locale" son los que se pueden usar, en
> linux puedes poner en una consola locale -a y te listará todos los
> posibles. Para español suele ser "es_ES.utf8", pero a menudo hay alias
> más cortos como "es"

Answer (score 2):

Lo que devuelve `calendar.month(año, mes)` es un string, obviamente con un formato bastante bonito, cada linea está definida por un salto de línea (`\n`) por lo que podemos hacer una separación de acuerdo a eso.

```py
calendario = calendar.month(año, mes).split("\n")
```

lo que nos devolverá (con la entrada `1/1/2022`):

```py
['    January 2022',
 'Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su',
 '                1  2',
 ' 3  4  5  6  7  8  9',
 '10 11 12 13 14 15 16',
 '17 18 19 20 21 22 23',
 '24 25 26 27 28 29 30',
 '31',
 '']
```

Y lo único que debemos de hacer es reemplazar las 2 primeras líneas.

```py
#reemplazamos las 2 primeras
calendario[:2] = ["", "Lu Ma Mx Ju Vi Sa Do"]
print("\n".join(calendario)) #volvemos a unir todo e imprimimos
```

Quedando como resultado:

```
Lu Ma Mx Ju Vi Sa Do
                1  2
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31
```